# Phalcon - render controller from view

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

Is it possible in Phalcon to render controller from view with Volt?

Like it is done in Symfony:

```
{{ render(controller('AcmeArticleBundle:Article:recentArticles', { 'max': 3 })) }}
```

Purpose: create incapsulated component with complex logic, views, assets and reuse it in multiple places

Comment: **No**. What do you want to achieve? I am sure there is another way to get to the same result.

Comment: @Timothy I want to render some "component" that is fully incapsulated, has own logic, views, assets and can be reused in multiple places. I tried some another ways but they looked like huge bicycle with dirty unclear code shared all over application. Is there a normal way to do it?

Comment: I did some looking around on the Phalcon forums and found [this post](https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/1281/how-can-i-call-another-controller-action-params-from-inside-a-vi#C4554). You'll need to add the `public function request(array $location, $data = null)` code to your bootstrap file and then you can request the content of another controller/action inside an action like `$this->app->request(['controller' => 'Article','action' => 'recentArticles'])`

Answer (score 0):

Better just use some service or pass parameter to view and include some other view etc.